# Get photo from telegram and post to Strapi via Axios

Tags: post, axios, telegram, strapi

Hi I'm trying to POST image to Strapi via api/uploads with Axios

With code below I have reponse with code 200, but in Strapi UI get file with no image, but with other parameters.
[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBKbK.png)

```js
return bot.getFileLink(msg.photo[0].file_id).then((resp) => {
                    axios.get(resp, { responseType: 'buffer' }) // geting img from telegram link
                        .then(axres => {
                            const buffer = Buffer.from(axres.data) // make Buffer obj
                            const imgdata = new formdata()
                            imgdata.append('files', buffer, { filename: resp }) // append to FormData object
                            axios.post(`http://localhost:1337/api/upload`, imgdata, {
                                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
                              })
                                .then(response => {
                                    console.log(response);
                                })
                                .catch(err => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                })
                        })
                })
```

In docs provided example with FormData in body option, but in this case I have error "Bad request 400"

```js
await fetch('/api/upload', {
      method: 'post',
      body: new FormData(e.target)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. With "binary" endocding in Buffer it works perfect.

```js
return bot.getFileLink(msg.photo[0].file_id).then((resp) => {
                    axios.get(resp, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
                        .then(axres => {
                            const buffer = Buffer.from(axres.data, 'binary')
                            const imgdata = new formdata()
                            imgdata.append('files', buffer, { filename: resp })
                            console.log(buffer)
                            axios.post(`http://localhost:1337/api/upload`, imgdata, {
                                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
                              })
                                .then(response => {
                                    console.log('ok');
                                })
                                .catch(err => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                })
                        })
                })
```